# Please clarify the query used in Neo4j online course

Tags: neo4j

I am going through the online course at http://www.neo4j.org/learn/online_course.

In that under the section (Graph LAB) - (Paths), the below query was used to RETURN all of the actors and directors in all of the movies.

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d)
RETURN a.name, m.title, d.name;
```

It is perfectly alright.

To the next question "How would you change this query to RETURN only the directors who acted in their own movies?"

They gave the solution as change (d) to (a). So the query is,

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(a)
RETURN a.name, m.title, a.name;
```

When i execute this query it throws output as "Unforgiven, Clint Eastwood".

But my doubt is when i look at the interactive network diagram, the node "Clint Eastwood" was connected to the "Movie" node only through the relationship "DIRECTED". There was not a separate relationship "ACTED_IN". Then how neo4j selects only "Unforgiven, Clint Eastwood" and discards other directors.

Please clarify this. Is my understanding wrong.

r karthik.

Comment: I have just now ran the query                                    `code` MATCH (person)-[rel]->(movie {title:"Unforgiven"})
RETURN person, type(rel), movie `code`. I got two rows for "Clint Eastwood",  for DIRECTED and ACTED_IN. But then why the visualization doesn't shows the two relationship separately. Is it ovelayed?. But it should not overlay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `DIRECTED` relationship  is overlaying the `ACTED_IN` one. You can see the `ACTED_IN` relationship after deleting the `DIRECTED` relationship:

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[d:DIRECTED]-(a)
DELETE d;
```

I agree that the visualization *should* somehow avoid letting overlays like this happen. You should bring this to the attention of the neo4j folks. At the very least, they may want to change the tutorial to avoid this situation.

Comment: Now in Neo4j 2.2.x relationships curve when there are more than one so that you can see both!

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(a) 
RETURN a.name, m.title;
```